# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(1-r^n) \to 0 \text{ as } r \to 1^-.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive terms and suppose $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty.$$ Prove (from first principles) that $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(1-r^n) \to 0 \text{ as } r \to 1^-.$$

Comment: Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Show - by splitting the series at a strategically chosen point - that for all $r$ close enough to $1$, you have $\sum a_n(1-r^n) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Yeah, it was the splitting part that I was missing. I was trying to do it all at once and running into the problem of $\delta \to 0$. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n < \infty$ and fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Clearly $a_n (1-r^n) \leq a_n$ for all $r \in[0,1)$ and $n \geq 1$, so $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n (1-r^n) \leq \displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n < \infty$ for all $r \in [0,1)$. Moreover, since $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges, there exists $N \geq 1$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_N^\infty a_n (1-r^n) \leq \displaystyle\sum_N^\infty a_n < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $r \in [0,1)$. Now, for all $n \in \{1,\ldots, N\}$ we have that $a_n r^n \to a_n$ as $r \to 1$ from below by continuity. That is, there exists $\delta_n \in (0,1)$ such that for all $r \in (\delta_n,1)$, $a_n - a_nr^n < \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2N}$. Choose $\delta = \displaystyle\max_{1 \leq n \leq N} \delta_n$. Then given $r \in (\delta,1)$, we have that $$\displaystyle\sum_1^N a_n(1-r^n) = \displaystyle\sum_1^N (a_n - a_nr^n) < \displaystyle\sum_1^N \frac{\varepsilon}{2N} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ and so that $$\sum_1^\infty a_n(1-r^n) = \sum_1^N a_n(1-r^n) + \sum_N^\infty a_n(1-r^n) <\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 3):

This is famously known as Abel's theorem. We can phrase your statement as follows:

> **Theorem** Suppose that $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geqslant 0}a_n$ converges, and define for $|x|<1$ the function $\displaystyle  f(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}a_nx^n$ Then $\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to 1^{-}}f(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}a_n$.

$(1)$ Denote by $A$ your sum. Since we're working in $|x|<1$, absolute convergence lets us write $$\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{{1 - x}}\left( {f\left( x \right) - A} \right) &= \frac{1}{{1 - x}}\sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{a_n}{x^n}}  - \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {A{x^n}}  \cr 
   &= \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{x^n}} \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{a_n}{x^n}}  \cr 
   &= \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_n}} {x^n}}  - \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {A{x^n}} \cr 
   &= \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} \left(\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_n}} -A\right){x^n}   \end{align} $$

$(2)$ You know that given $\varepsilon$ you can make $$\left|{\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_n}}  - A}\right|<\varepsilon$$

and moreover we can assert there is a uniform bound $$\left| {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_n}}  - A} \right| < M$$

$(3)$ Combine this and the fact that

$$\displaylines{
  \sum\limits_{n \geqslant N} {{x^n}}  = \frac{{{x^N}}}{{1 - x}} \cr 
  \sum\limits_{n < N} {{x^n}}  = \frac{{1 - {x^N}}}{{1 - x}} \cr} $$

to obtain a really nice $x$ dependent upper bound of $|f(x)-A|$. Then, "let" $x\to 1^-$.

---

*Spoiler ahead*

**Proof**  Let $A$ be our sum. Observe that for $|x|<1$, we have that $$\frac{1}{1-x}f(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^n$$

Thus,

> $$\frac{1}{1-x}\left( f(x)-A\right)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k-A\right)x^n$$

By hypothesis, there exists $N>0$ such that whenever $n\geqslant N$ we have

> $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k-A\right|<\varepsilon$$

Since we can assume $1-x>0$, we can write

> $$\begin{align}  \frac{1}{{1 - x}}\left| {f(x) - A} \right| &\leqslant \sum\limits_{n < N} {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_k}}  - A} \right){x^n}}  + \sum\limits_{n \geqslant N} {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_k}}  - A} \right){x^n}} \\  &\leqslant \sum\limits_{n < N} {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_k}}  - A} \right){x^n}}  + \varepsilon \sum\limits_{n \geqslant N} {{x^n}} \\ &\leqslant \sum\limits_{n < N} {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_k}}  - A} \right){x^n}}  + \varepsilon \frac{{{x^N}}}{{1 - x}} \end{align} $$

Now, let $M$ be a bound for the differences of partials sums, then we may write

> $$\frac{1}{{1 - x}}\left| {f(x) - A} \right| \leqslant M\frac{{1 - {x^N}}}{{1 - x}} + \varepsilon \frac{{{x^N}}}{{1 - x}}$$

Thus, we obtain

> $$\left| {f(x) - A} \right| \leqslant M\left( {1 - {x^N}} \right) + \varepsilon {x^N}$$

Now, we can choose $\delta$ such that whenever $1-x<\delta$, we have $1-x^N<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$, and since trivially $x^N<1$, we obtain for $x\in (1-\delta,1)$ that

> $$\left| {f(x) - A} \right| \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}2+\frac{\varepsilon}2<\varepsilon $$

$\blacktriangle$

Comment: Ugh, seems a spoiler isn't not working.

Comment: @user93370 I don't know what you did, so I cannot tell.

Comment: Suppose $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n < \infty$ and fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Clearly $a_n (1-r^n) \leq a_n$ for all $r \in[0,1)$ and $n \geq 1$, so $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n (1-r^n) < \displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n < \infty$ for all $r \in [0,1)$. Moreover, since $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges, there exists $N \geq 1$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_N^\infty a_n (1-r^n) < \displaystyle\sum_N^\infty a_n < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $r \in [0,1)$. Now, given $n \in \{1,\ldots, N\}$ we have that $a_n r^n \to a_n$ as $r \to 1$ from the left by continuity.

Comment: That is, there exists $\delta_n \in (0,1)$ such that for all $r \in (\delta_n,1)$, $a_n - a_nr^n < \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2N}$. Choose $\delta = \displaystyle\max_{1 \leq n \leq N} \delta_n$. Then given $r \in (\delta,1)$, we have that $$\displaystyle\sum_1^N a_n(1-r^n) = \displaystyle\sum_1^N (a_n - a_nr^n) < \displaystyle\sum_1^N \frac{\varepsilon}{2N} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ and so that $$\sum_1^\infty a_n(1-r^n) = \sum_1^N a_n(1-r^n) + \sum_N^\infty a_n(1-r^n) <\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

Comment: @user93370 Yes, that is great. It would be nice if you posted that as an answer to your question, so both approaches are kept in record. Note that my approach is not that different from yours, it simply uses a nice "multply by $(1-x)^{-1}$ to collect terms into sums" trick, if you may. =)

Comment: I will do that! (I'm now to the site and don't know all the rules).

Comment: I find it silly that you have to juggle coefficients so that the final result is "$< \epsilon$". To me, it is just as good if the bound is $2\epsilon$ or $17\epsilon$ or any constant times $\epsilon$.

Comment: @martycohen It's a personal preference, mainly aesthetic. And in this case it is a pretty simple "juggling". Of course any multiple of $\varepsilon $ works.